# Spring referring bean present in other xml using local attribute of ref tag

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I am creating sample spring program to understand, local attribute of ref tag.

I have created two bean files

first one [applicationcontext.xml]

```
    <bean class="org.vik.spring.SequenceGenerator" name="sequenceProperty_Other">
         <property name="prefix">
            <ref local="prefixGeneratorOther" />
         </property>
        <property name="suffix" value="23"></property>
    </bean>
```

Second xml file [prefix_context.xml]

```
<bean class="org.vik.spring.DatePrefixGenerator" id="prefixGeneratorOther" p:prefix="other"/>
```

I have created app context like below

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext  = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml" ,"prefix_context.xml");
```

When I request for bean "sequenceProperty_Other", spring successfully returns it

```
SequenceGenerator sequenceConstrutornerator = applicationContext.getBean( "sequenceProperty_Other",SequenceGenerator.class);
```

What I could understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740322/when-to-use-ref-bean-and-when-to-use-ref-local-in-spring), is that as "prefixGeneratorOther" bean in not in same xml file (applicationcontext.xml) and I am using local attribute to refer it, Spring should through exception. But in my case its working. Am I missing some thing.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- <bean class="org.vik.spring.SequenceGenerator" name="sequence"> </bean> -->

<bean class="org.vik.spring.DatePrefixGenerator" id="prefixGenerator"
    p:prefix="122333">

</bean>
<bean class="org.vik.spring.SequenceGenerator" name="sequenceProperty_Locale">
    <property name="prefix">
        <ref local="prefixGenerator" />
    </property>

    <property name="suffix" value="23"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.vik.spring.SequenceGenerator" name="sequenceProperty_Other">
    <property name="prefix">
        <ref local="prefixGeneratorOther" />
    </property>
    <property name="suffix" value="23"></property>
</bean>
```

prefix_context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="org.vik.spring.DatePrefixGenerator" id="prefixGeneratorOther"     p:prefix="other"/>

</beans>
```

Java class

```
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml",
            "prefix_context.xml");

    System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean("prefixGenerator", PrefixGenerator.class).getPrefix());


    SequenceGenerator sequenceProperty = applicationContext.getBean("sequenceProperty_Locale",
            SequenceGenerator.class);
    System.out.println(sequenceProperty);


    SequenceGenerator sequenceConstrutornerator = applicationContext.getBean("sequenceProperty_Other",
            SequenceGenerator.class);
    System.out.println(sequenceConstrutornerator);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `prefixGeneratorOther` beans in applicationcontext.xml as well?

Comment: Or maybe the xml files you are using in your ApplicationContext are not the ones you think you are using.

Comment: I have verified that applicationcontext.xml doesnt have bean prefixGeneratorOther. To verify that code is referring to same xml file, I have renamed the xml file, spring throw exception "applicationcontext.xml file not fouund"..

Comment: In my opinion, the code you posted shouldn't work.

Comment: I my opinion also it should not work, thats why I have posted it.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using one of Spring 3.x versions. Is that right? If the two xml files are not large, can you post them in full here?

Comment: Yes I am using 3.2.3

Comment: Please, post more code from the class where you use that app context. For example, the class and method where this `ApplicationContext applicationContext  = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml" ,"prefix_context.xml");` comes from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59365/discussion-between-stifler-and-andrei-stefan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular behavior works with any version after Spring 3.1.0 (included) in the 3.x branch. If you test this with the latest 3.0.x (which is 3.0.7) you'll get an exception. If you test with Spring 4, you'll get an exception, but a different one.

If you take a look carefully at the exception in Spring 3.0.7, this refers to XML parsing:

```
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
```

which means the restriction is at xml schema level (and I believe it's at Java code level, as well).

This behavior has changed in Spring 3.1.0 (and after) because of this [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8179). From all those JIRA issue it is linked to, [this one](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1886) seems to explain what happened: the restriction has been eliminated from 3.1 schema and the `ref local` entered in a kind of "deprecated" state (because in 3.1.x and 3.2.x one can use it) and in Spring 4 `ref local` has been entirely eliminated. In Spring 4 [the documentation says `ref local` is not supported anymore](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8182) and, also, the xsd schema has been updated (in the sense that `ref` doesn't accept `local` anymore).