# spring core prolem in spring bean creation

Tags: spring

my XML file in my spring application have this schema....my question is it show's 
"Attribute name "ref" associated with an element type "property" must be followed   by the ' = ' character." why where id=sb?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd"
     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">    
   <bean id="dao" class="com.nareshit.dao.DAOBean"/>

    <bean id="sb" class="com.nareshit.service.ServiceBean">
         <property name="daoBean" ref local="daoBean"/>  
    </bean>     

    <bean id="cb" class="com.nareshit.controller.ControllerBean">
    <property name="serviceBean" ref local="sb"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `<property>` element, `ref` is an attribute that requires a value. So you need to have

```
<property ... ref="something" ... />
```

[If you really meant to use `local`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740322/when-to-use-ref-bean-and-when-to-use-ref-local-in-spring), remove the `ref` element altogether.

Comment: Thank you mr. Delimanolis .you are absolutely correct.its my fault to pass arguments in constructors.