# Attribute 'local' is not allowed to appear in element 'ref' in Spring 4.1.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am currently going through [Mkyong Spring 3.0 tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-reference-example/).

He goes on to clarify these 2 basic things.
**1. Bean in different XML files**

> If you are referring to a bean in different XML file, 
>       you can reference it with a ‘ref‘ tag, ‘bean‘ attribute.

**2. Bean in same XML file**

> If you are referring to a bean in same XML file, 
>       you can reference it with ‘ref‘ tag, ‘local‘ attribute.

The only thing I can make out is that the `local attribute` is not supported any more in version `4.1.`5. For the timebeing, I have sticked to the

```
<ref bean="thebeaninstance"/>
```

and it works for both. `<ref bean="...">` requires only it to be in the `same context`, or in a `parent context`.

But i am looking for something by which i will be able to resolve the difference once if somehow i encounter same ids in 2 different beans, and wish to refer to the one defined in different XML, since preference goes to the one defines in the same XML. Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use <ref bean> and when to use <ref local> in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740322/when-to-use-ref-bean-and-when-to-use-ref-local-in-spring)

Answer (score 13):

Spring dropped support for the local ref elements in version 4.0.1. This is from the notes:

> Removed the ref 'local' attribute in spring-beans-4.0.xsd since 'local' lost its differentiating role to a regular bean ref back in the 3.1 days when we started allowing for the same bean id to reappear in a different beans section of the same configuration file (with a different profile). Issue: SPR-10437

See here: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/0fc5a5d912a4548f9bbf6f14024dc489d94cb2c9)

Basically, you should use the **bean** element.