# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'local' is not allowed to appear in element 'ref'. root-context.xml

Tags: spring

I using spring framework, velocity and sring rest full web services.
In my root-context.xml it is complaining about me using "" which is referencing the following:

Here is the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<beans>
<bean id="sender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="username" value="jadeite1000@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="Jadeite1"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="velocityEngine">
        <ref bean="velocityEngine"/>

    </property>

</bean>     


<bean id="emailEcardConfig" class="com.email.EcardMailConfig">

    <property name="from">
        <value>abc@yahoo.com</value>
    </property>


    <property name="subject">
        <value>Testing Email!</value>
    </property>


    <property name="htmlTemplatePath">
        <value>EcardHtmlTemplate.vm</value>
    </property>

    <property name="velocityEngine">
        <ref local="velocityEngine"/>
    </property>

</bean>



<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
<property name="resourceLoaderPath"><value>/WEB-INF/classes/velocity/</value></property>

</bean>
```

Any hint or help is greatly appreciated it!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove "local" from your code It is no more allowed in Spring

```
<property name="velocityEngine">
    <ref local="velocityEngine"/>
</property>
```

Comment: I checked also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049183/attribute-local-is-not-allowed-to-appear-in-element-ref-in-spring-4-1-5