# Spring:- What is the difference between ref attribute and ref tag?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am pretty new to spring and have been learning from the official docs. I found that to inject a dependency using XML configuration, there are two ways to declare **refs**:-

```
<bean name="parentBean" class="com.example.ParentBean">
   <property name="dependency1" ref="com.example.Dependency1"/>
</bean>
```

Or, I can use the ref tag, like:-

```
    <bean name="parentBean" class="com.example.ParentBean">
       <property name="dependency1"> 
         <ref bean="com.example.Dependency1"/>
       </property> 
    </bean>
```

Is there any difference between the two **ref** declarations? If not, why does spring allow two different methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments in the [XSD](https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd) (see `<xsd:complexType name="propertyType">`):

> **`ref` attribute:** A short-cut alternative to a nested `<ref bean='...'/>`.

Is there any difference between the two ref declarations?
*No.*

If not, why does spring allow two different methods?
*Convenience.*

Answer (score 1):

The core purpose is the same. It's just <ref..> tag has its own attributes:

[When to use <ref bean> and when to use <ref local> in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740322/when-to-use-ref-bean-and-when-to-use-ref-local-in-spring)