# upgrade to spring boot by keeping the old xml config gives error : Attribute 'local' is not allowed to appear in element 'ref'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I was upgrading a project to spring boot, which is in an old version of spring now.

There is a dependency in this project (I don't have control in it) which is still in old spring.
This dependency provides a context xml config file , which is imported in the application context file of the project I am upgrading, as shown below.

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-accesscontrol.xml" />
```

But, in this imported xml file local ref is used which is not allowed in new spring.

```
<list>
                <ref local="bean1" />
                <ref local="bean2" />
            </list>
```

When I run the application I am getting below error in the log:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 82;
> columnNumber: 39; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'local' is not
> allowed to appear in element 'ref'.   at
> java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
> at
> java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
> at
> java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)

How can I make it work when I don't have control in this old versioned dependency?

Comment: request them to change it, if that isn't possible you cannot use this XML but have to rewrite it either in a new XML or Java Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in
[When to use <ref bean> and when to use <ref local> in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740322/when-to-use-ref-bean-and-when-to-use-ref-local-in-spring)

local is not supported. So use bean instead of local in applicationContext-accesscontrol.xml :

```
            <list>
                <ref bean="bean1" />
                <ref bean="bean2" />
            </list>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question I can't change applicationContext-accesscontrol.xml. It comes from the a dependency.